# Proper HRESULT for "this object is not completely initialized"

Tags: com, error-handling, hresult

I'm writing a COM object that provides access to a service that must be explicitly connected before calls can succeed.

Is there a generic `HRESULT` code that describes that the callee object is in a state where it is unprepared to handle calls, ideally with the implication that this is the caller's fault?

Currently I'm using `E_FAIL`, which is too generic for my taste; `OLE_E_BLANK` might be an option, however this is not an OLE object and I'd rather not return a confusing error code.

Comment: E_PENDING, maybe.  Implement IErrorInfo so it doesn't matter.

Comment: E_ILLEGAL_METHOD_CALL probably? E_PENDING sounds like you started some async operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that E_NOT_VALID_STATE would be closest to what you want to convey. 
But, as Hans says, implement IErrorInfo to give chapter and verse.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that because the customer still uses VS 2008, where the symbol does not exist yet. Thanks!